# Animate complete infinite loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, promise, each

I am trying to make animations to animate one after another.

The way I did it was like this:

```
$(class).animate(
    {something},
    {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function(){
                      $(class).animate(
                          {something},
                          {
                              duration: 1000,
                              complete:  function(){
                              // More to animate when previous animation is done
                          }
                  });
    }
});
```

Until now, this worked quite well. My problem is the following:

To trigger this chain of animations, I am using a click on an element. When you click on that element, there is a variable "ongoing" that becauses true so that it is not possible to reclick on that element because the end of the animation has not yet been reached.

The deepest animation in this chain of animations is the following.

```
complete: function(){
    $(few divs).each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate(
            {"opacity": 1},
            {
                duration:2000,
                complete: function(){
                      console.log(i + " finished"); //
                      if(i == 2){ // 3 divs
                          ongoing = false; // All the animations are finished, allowed to reclick
                      }
                }
                delay += 2000;
            });
}
```

The problem with this is that it shows 3 times 0,1,2.

```
0 finished
1 finished
2 finished
0 finished
1 finished
2 finished
0 finished
1 finished
2 finished
```

I then tried this:

```
complete: function(){
    selected = text;

    $(few divs).each(function(i){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({"opacity": 1}, 2000);
        delay += 2000;
    }).promise().done(function(){ // All each's are finished
        ongoing = false;
        console.log("finished");
    });
}
```

With this example, there is also an infinite loop with the "finished"...

What exactly is going on in my code and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Have you tried making the call recursively instead of hard coding every level? Also, why not put the function as the callback instead of in the completed event as shown further down the page on the [jQuery animate page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: No i haven't tried but I will. Do you know what is the difference between the callback function and the complete parameter of the function animate?

Comment: Actually there doesn't seem to be any difference as far as I can read. I have never seen anyone put the functions in the Complete event instead of just having it as a regular callback, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`}).promise().done(function(){ // all each's are finished`

This is wrong - it is always executing immediately.

You need to push the deferred objects of your `animate()` into an array; consider the following example.

```
var promises = [];
$(few divs).each(function(i){ 
    promises.push(
        $(this)
            .delay(i * 2000)
            .animate({
                "opacity": 1
            }, 2000)
    );
})
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {});
```

Comment: Your `apply` is missing the first parameter, `thisArg`.

Comment: @oxynad You can't just say something doesn't work. At least post the code. And if you are using `console.log()`, why not put that in tons of locations, so you can visibly see the execution order of events? The code snippet I provided will only execute it's `done()` function once, unless the entire snippet is called multiple times.

Comment: I added a console.log in the function() and for some reason, it showed 3 "finished" about 6 seconds after the animation was done. Why is that? I will test some more

Comment: @oxynad These animations inside the `each()` are called with increasing delays. The `done()` function will execute as soon as the last animation finishes. You can add some callback functions to your `animate()` method to see exactly when they each finish.

Answer (score 0):

The "increasing delay" approach actually gives a set of individual animations each with a predicted start time to give an end-to-end sequence effect - with the potential for timing errors.

A better approach would be to create a genuine animation sequence with guaranteed timimg, by building a `.then()` chain.

```
complete:  function() {
    var promise = $.when();
    $(few divs).each(function() {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            return $(this).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000).promise();
        });
    });
    promise.done(function() { // All animates are complete
        ongoing = false;
        console.log('finished');
    });
}
```

Or, slightly more compactly using Array's `.reduce()` method:

```
complete: function() {
    $(few divs).get().reduce(function(promise, el) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return $(el).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000).promise();
        });
    }, $.when()).done(function() { // All animates are complete
        ongoing = false;
        console.log('finished');
    });
}
```